# How can I group by date in market_profile package in python?

Tags: python, r, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I want to group by day so I can create a market profile for every day.
This is my data frame. It's a usual OHLC data that goes from 2006-04-13 to 2021-06-14 and I add a day_month variable.

**Python**

```
df.head()
                       Open    High    Low    Close Volume  day_month
 2006-04-13 10:00:00 1921.75 1922.00 1918.00 1918.25 11782 2006-04-13
 2006-04-13 10:30:00 1918.25 1931.75 1918.00 1931.00 39744 2006-04-13
 2006-04-13 11:00:00 1931.25 1934.00 1929.00 1930.25 34385 2006-04-13
 2006-04-13 11:30:00 1930.50 1932.00 1928.50 1931.25 13539 2006-04-13
 2006-04-13 12:00:00 1931.25 1932.25 1928.25 1928.75 10045 2006-04-13
```

This is the info of my dataframe

```
[5 rows x 8 columns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 57172 entries, 2006-04-13 10:00:00 to 2021-06-14 16:00:00
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------     --------------  -----         
 0   Open       57172 non-null  float64       
 1   High       57172 non-null  float64       
 2   Low        57172 non-null  float64       
 3   Close      57172 non-null  float64       
 4   Volume     57172 non-null  int32         
 5   day_month  57172 non-null  datetime64[ns]
```

The packages I am using

```
from market_profile import MarketProfile
import pandas as pd
from dfply import *
```

I create this function for the market profile

```
def mp_va(df):
    mp = MarketProfile(df, tick_size = 0.25)
    mp_slice = mp[df.index.min():df.index.max()]
    return mp_slice.value_area[0]
```

What I need is the dataframe can be group or subset by each day. Each day has different hours that this market profile takes to make the calculation.

This was my first attemp:

```
df.groupby(['day_month']).mp_va(df)
```

My second attempt was:

```
from dfply import *
df >> group_by(X.day_month) >> mutate(va_low = mp_va(df))
```

The above codes gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'mp_va'

Detailed traceback: 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Pastor\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 580, in __getattr__
    f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{attr}'"
```

I tried using R to solve this problem from the `reticulate` package

**R**

```
library(reticulate)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
# I store the function in the R enviroment
mp_va <- py$mp_va
df_va <- df %>% group_by(day_month) %>%  mutate(va_low = mp_va(df))
```

The above code gives me the same value for `va_low` all days, I think the problem is that the function doesn't calculate by each day.

My question is how can I make the calculation for each day? The function actually works when I subset by each day, since it is a large dataset I want to run this automatically. I also want to store the output in a variable to have the va_low on each day.

Using `subset` in R for one single day gives me :

```
df_2021 <- subset(df, day_month == "2021-06-14")
df_2006 <- subset(df, day_month == "2006-04-13")

mp_va(df_2021)
mp_va(df_2006)

[1] 13998.75
[2] 1927.5
```

The answer can be on python or R: The reason why I am using both is that market_profile is a python package and I didn't find any similar equivalent in R.

This is the python documentation for the package:
https://pypi.org/project/MarketProfile/

Comment: Have you tried `df.groupby('day_month').apply(mp_va)` ?

Comment: Yes! That's the answer. Thank you!

Comment: There you go @PastorSolo, I wrote it up as a nice answer with an explanation of why you need this function, and pointers on understanding the while `GroupBy` idiom. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good reference to understand this is the [**Group by: split-apply-combine**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/user_guide/groupby.html) user guide from the pandas doc.

There are several steps:

1. Splitting an object into groups

   You already have this right: `df.groupby('day_month')` allows to split your global dataframe into smaller dataframes that have the same `day_month` value.
2. Applying a function to each group independently

   Here there are a number of options. You could

   - aggregate the data: reduce it to a sum of the values in the group for example,
   - filter the data: select some of the groups,
   - transform the data: which operates on columns in your group and returns columns of the same shape, for example normalize values within each group by subtracting the average and dividing by the standard deviation
   - apply a function to the data: this is a catch-all (thus often slower than the other operations) that just passes each group of data to a function.

   Applying a function is usually done by calling `.agg(op)`, `.filter(op)`, `.transform(op)`, `.apply(op)` on the GroupBy result, where `op` that specifies which operation to perform.  This can be a string that names a pre-defined operation(`mean`, `sum`, etc.) or a function (such as `mp_va` in your case). However you can not call directly `GroupBy.mp_va()`. This wouldn’t specify what kind of operation is being done.
3. Combining the data

   This is just concatenating all the group-wise results into a single dataframe. This work is already done by `agg`, `apply`, and friends.

**It seems here that your function applies to each group dataframe, and not to its columns individually. Therefore you need `GroupBy.apply`.**

---

Basically you can think of the following code

```
df.groupby('day_month').apply(mp_va)
```

as being roughly the same as:

```
pd.concat([mp_va(group) for name, group in df.groupby('day_month')])
```

Here the steps are more obvious:

1. splitting is done by `.groupby('day_month')`
2. applying the function is done by `mp_va(group)`
3. combining the results together is done by `pd.concat`